# Attaching Custom Libraries to Drupal 10

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I'm trying to manually load the OwlCarousel2 Libraries on my Drupal 10 site. I have downloaded the library and updated the right files but it is not working (I don't want to use the Owlcarousel2 Drupal Module).

Here's what I've done:

mytheme.libraries.yml

```
  global-styling:
  version: VERSION
  js:
    js/global.js: {}
  css:
    component:
      css/style.css: {}
owlcarousel2:
  css:
    theme:
      /libraries/OwlCarousel2/dist/assets/owl.carousel.min.css: {}
      /libraries/OwlCarousel2/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css: {}
  js:
    /libraries/OwlCarousel2/dist/owl.carousel.min.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

global.js

```
 /**
 * @file
 * Global utilities.
 *
 */
(function ($) {
/**
* @file
* Javascript, modifications of DOM.
*
* Manipulates links to include jquery load funciton
*/

Drupal.behaviors.mytheme = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
      
  $(document).ready(function() {
    
    // Instantiate OwlCarousel2 plugin 
    $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();
    
  });
  
  }
}

}(jQuery));
```

My HTML

```
<!--  HTML -->
<div class="owl-carousel">
  <div> My Content </div>
  <div> My Content </div>
  <div> My Content </div>
  <div> My Content </div>
</div>
```